# How do I call a function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm unsure why my label will not change to the question string.

```
func GenerateQuestion(){
    let FirstNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))+1 // first number in sum
    let SecondNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))+1 // second number in sum
    let SymbolNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))+1 // number which decides the operator in sum
    var OperatorSymbol = ""
    var Question = "" // the question
    var Answer = Int() // holds answer of the sum
    var ButtonNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))+1 // number which chooses button to hold correct answer

    switch SymbolNo{
    case 1 : OperatorSymbol = "+";
    Question = "\(FirstNo) + \(SecondNo) = ?";
    self.Lbl.text = Question
    case 2 : OperatorSymbol = "-";
        Question = "\(FirstNo) - \(SecondNo) = ?";
        self.Lbl.text = Question
    case 3 : OperatorSymbol = "/";
        Question = "\(FirstNo) / \(SecondNo) = ?";
        self.Lbl.text = Question
    case 4 : OperatorSymbol = "x";
        Question = "\(FirstNo) x \(SecondNo) = ?;";
        self.Lbl.text = Question
    default : Question = ""
    }
```

I haven't called `func generateQuestion` as I don't know how to. What should I do?

Comment: It's generally recommended to use camel case function names in Swift, as stated in the official design guideline: http://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines

Comment: You state - *"I'm unsure why my label will not change"*. Then you state - *"I haven't called `func generateQuestion`"*. You just answered your own question.

Comment: *"What should I do?"* - Read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book.

Comment: Okay, my fault. I worded my question wrong, i understand why the label won't change, how can i call the function and where should i call it?

Comment: When do you want your label text to change? After a button press, something else...?

Comment: The label text should change as soon as the app loads up. The label becomes a question and the buttons will hold the answer, I'm just getting the label to change before i move forward with the code for the button.

Comment: Call this function from the `viewDidLoad` method of whatever view controller it is in.

Answer (score 1):

To call an instance of a function you type the function name followed by a pair of parentheses with or without an argument.

```
generateQuestion()
```

If you want something to be executed as soon as the app loads up you should type it into the viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    generateQuestion()
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

This is a good resource, as mentioned above.

Again, as mentioned above it is better to use `lowerCamelCase` for functions and variables and reserve `UpperCamelCase` for classes and structures. More can be found on that in the Swift guide.

Good luck!